# converting c# objectid to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a objectId on my mvc model which i want to sent to a mvc API call, which results in a

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

```
    <script>
    $(function () {


        $('.btn-saveshedule').click(function () {

            var selectedValue = $("#sel1 option:selected").val();

            var userid =@Model.Id.ToString();
            var json = getTimeSlotsInJson($('.schedule'), userid.str, selectedValue);

        });

    });


</script>
```

how on earth do i convert @Model.Id to a string?

Comment: What is your Model, and the `Id` type? (what do you expect `userid.str` to return)?

Comment: Put quotes around it. e.g. `'@Model.Id'`.

Comment: `var userid ='@Model.Id';`

Comment: Did you look at the resulting JavaScript? Did the JavaScript look valid to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put single quotes around it:

```
var userid ='@Model.Id.ToString()';
```